# Partition problem of set

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

> Let $A =\{1, 2, 3,..., 100\}$. We partition $A$ into $10$ subsets $A_1,A_2,...A_{10}$
>   each of size $10$. A second partition into $10$ sets of size $10$ each is given by
>   $B_1,B_2,...B_{10}$. Prove that we can rearrange the indices of the second partition
>   so that $A_{i}\cap B_{i}\not=\varnothing$.

Comment: This is obviously impossible. For example, suppose $A_1=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$ and $B_i$ contains $i$. Did you mean to say "Prove that we can rearrange the indices of the second partition so that $A_i \cap B_i$ is *not* empty"?

Comment: Yep. That's exactly what the question wants.

Answer (score 4):

Do you know Hall's marriage theorem?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem

It is not hard to see that $k$ sets of size 10 each have to share elements with at least $k$ sets in the other partition, so the theorem applies.

ETA:
The $k$ sets have a total of $10k$ elements, so you need at least $k$ sets in the other partition to cover all of these elements, since $k-1$ sets have two few elements.

Answer (score 0):

Put $P_1=\{A_1,A_2,...,A_{10}\}$ and $P_2=\{B_1,B_2,...,B_{10}\}$

Take any $X \subset P_1$ and let $N(X)\subset P_2$ be the set of all neighbors of vertices in $X$. Say $|X|=k$ and $|N(X)| = l$. Then we have $$\bigcup _{A\in X} A =\bigcup _{B\in N(X)} B  $$
since set on left and sets on right are disjoint we have $$10k= \sum  _{A\in X} |A| =\sum _{B\in N(X)} |B| =10l $$ we have $k=l$ so $|X|\leq |N(X)|$ and so Hall condition is fulfilled and we are done.